# Should I use the same arrival/departure dates indicated in my I-94 when completing my N-400 Application for US Naturalization?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

When applying for U.S. citizenship, in the [N-400 Application for Naturalization Form](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716010951/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0)), in the travel history section, one has to indicate the "Date You Left the United States (mm/dd/yyyy)"? and "Date You Returned to the United States (mm/dd/yyyy)":

[image]

For [one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168885/1810) of my trips, my I-94 travel history mentions that I arrived to the US on November 12, 2019, even though my recollection is that I passed US immigration on November 11, 2019. This inconsistency may stem from the fact that the I-94 website is [using](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168887/1810) the Eastern Time zone to decide the dates of departure and arrival (in my case I arrived at LAX airport on November 12, 2019 in Eastern Time and November 11, 2019 in local time, i.e. Pacific Time).

Should I still use the same arrival/departure dates indicated in my  I-94 when completing my N-400 Application for US Naturalization, or instead based these dates on my recollection?

Comment: Your lucky number is 800-375-5283 look for it everywhere

Comment: @chx thanks, it's good to have the information directly available too somewhere on the web. I believe that's partly why stack exchange was created, coincidentally.

Comment: no, saving two seconds of Googling was not why SE was created and this question is even worse than your usual ones because any advice you get here is suspect. You are going to gamble your N-400 on some layperson's advice? What madness. Now, if you were posting this _after_ calling USCIS to share the information, that'd be different and useful.

Comment: @chx why do you think that nobody before me has called the USCIS?

Answer (score 2):

You should not worry about what it says on the I-94 site. You are responsible for the honesty and correctness of your answers on your application. You are not responsible for the correctness of the information on the I-94 site. So give the answer that you think is most correct for the facts of the situation, rather than trying to alter it to match something else.

Answer (score 0):

The N-400 form says the following in the travel section:

> List below all the trips of 24 hours or longer that you have taken outside the United States during the last s years. Start with your most recent trip and work backwards. If you need extra space, use additional sheets of paper.

So if you’re not sure, put “see attachment” in one of the rows and add an explanation of your situation. Attach both the I-94 and your ticket copy as proof of when your travel has occurred. This way no one can accuse you of putting down the wrong dates.

Comment: I would consider this downright bad advice. The only right answer is to call USCIS and _ask_ . You do not _know_ this and making a mistake in a form like is extremely dangerous. As I noted here, taking advice from random strangers in immigration matters is not a great idea. Talk to the relevant authorities and/or a lawyer. This is _not_ why SE was created, the question should be closed. Yes, this answer is what I would do but I would never advise it to anyone else.

Comment: @chx 1) do you want to close all immigration questions? And maybe the entirely law.SE too? 2) one shouldn't have to pay a lawyer to file n400. Also, lawyers sometimes make mistakes. Always better to have multiple sources of information.

Comment: @chx Franck Dernoncourt has a point.  If I'd relied on the immigration advice I received from perhaps the most prominent immigration law firm in Amsterdam, I would not now be a citizen of the Netherlands.  As it happened, I knew that the advice was incorrect, so I saved myself a good deal of money and hassle by dealing with the Dutch authorities directly.

Comment: @chx sure, feel free to call said number and let us know what they say in a comment. It’s very common for people to do just that on StackExchange. Or even better - email them and post a copy of the response.